# URL based windows in Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, titanium, appcelerator

I have some questions

- How do you use url based windows in titanium?
- Does setting the url to a ".js" file run all the code in the file or does it just open the window?
- How does it come to know about the exact Window? Is there any naming convention required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No naming conventions and you just use the path. `window.url = windows/window1.js` Also the code run when the window is open as you correctly guessed :-)

```
var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    url: 'windows/window1.js'
});
```

From [docs](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.Window-object): "url to a JavaScript file with the windows instructions. this window will create a new JavaScript sub-context that will run in its own thread and global variable space."

I think this [sub-contexts](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.Window-object#sub-contexts) info will help you understand them the most.

Comment: can we link multiple js file to window?